# How to get information from the field without using an onchange event but a button with the onclick event in LWC

Tags: lightning-web-components

```
<lightning-input label="Enter Account Name" name="Name" type="text" value={Acc.Name}></lightning-input>

<lightning-input label="Enter Phone Number" name="Phone" type="number" value={Acc.Phone}></lightning-input>

<lightning-button label="Submit" onclick={Save} variant="brand"></lightning-button>
```

In lightning compoent, i use:

compoent html.

```
<aura:attribute name ="Acc" type="object" default="">

<lightning:input label="Enter Account Name" name="Name" type="text" value={!v.Acc.Name}></lightning:input>

<lightning:input label="Enter Phone Number" name="Phone" type="number" value={!v.Acc.Phone}></lightning:input>

<lightning:button label="Submit" onclick={!c.Save} variant="brand"></lightning:button>
```

javascript -Ctrl.....

```
Save : function(compoent,event,helper){

var Acc = compoent.get('v.Acc');
......
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Why not just natively use `lightning-record-edit-form` , its submit method that will allow you to get all data in one shot. No need to iterate through all input fields.

```
<template>
    <lightning-record-edit-form record-id="003XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"
                                object-api-name="Contact">
        <lightning-messages>
        </lightning-messages>
        <lightning-output-field field-name="AccountId">
        </lightning-output-field>
        <lightning-input-field field-name="FirstName">
        </lightning-input-field>
        <lightning-input-field field-name="LastName">
        </lightning-input-field>
        <lightning-input-field field-name="Email">
        </lightning-input-field>
        <lightning-button
            class="slds-m-top_small"
            variant="brand"
            type="submit"
            name="update"
            label="Update">
        </lightning-button>
    </lightning-record-edit-form>
</template>
```

JS:

```
handleSubmit(event){
   event.preventDefault();       // stop the form from submitting
   const fields = event.detail.fields; //Get all fields data here.
   fields.Street = '32 Prince Street';
   this.template.querySelector('lightning-record-edit-form').submit(fields);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The corresponding code in LWC should look like this:

```
Save() {
    let myInputs = this.template.querySelectorAll("lightning-input");
    myInputs.forEach(input => console.log(input.value));
  }
```

Nevertheless I would recommend to rename `Save` to sth. like `buttonClickHandler` to follow best practices.

Comment: If your using the onchange event for each field would it be a good practice?

Comment: it depends what is best in terms of usability - for a phone number I wouldn't to a on change as this will trigger on each keystroke. Maybe using the blur event when the user switches focus? Button is also ok in my mind

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
save() {
    const myInputFields = this.template.querySelectorAll("lightning-input");
    const result = {};
    myInputFields.forEach(input => {
         result[input.name] = input.value;      
    });
    console.log(result);
}
```

Comment: Ok, thanks for the answer

Answer (score 0):

It's not that easy... you can either include

.html

```
<div id="input-form-id">
    <lightning-input type="text" name="Name" label="Name" ></lightning-input>
    <lightning-input type="text" name="Phone" label="phone"></lightning-input>
    <lightning-button label="Submit" onclick={Save} variant="brand"></lightning-button>
</div>
```

.js
import { LightningElement } from 'lwc';

export default class LightningExampleInputDate extends LightningElement {

```
inputValues = {};
Save(){
    this.template.querySelectorAll('lightning-input').forEach(ele =>{
        console.log(ele.name);
        this.inputValues[`${ele.name}`] = ele.value;
    });

    console.log(JSON.stringify(this.inputValues));
}
```

}

or create a custom element and use the element in the queryall :)